# Test Code and Test classes - we need a wiki?

Tags: discussion

Plenty of Testcode/TestClasses/75%issues etc.

I think it's time we start and build a wiki on:

Why is my Testclass not ***_*__*_***...

Comment: This would be fantastic.  Having the wiki would make the experiencing of having "help i can't deploy" get closed repeatedly.

Comment: I agree with Ralph. There are many other things that could be added too, like how to create test data (not covered particularly well elsewhere on the net that I've seen), when to initiate `Test.startTest` and `Test.stopTest`, SystemAsserts or when to use `SeeAllData` all things that would be especially helpful to newbies. Including other "best practices" or "recommendations" like not to hard code a UserID, UserName or ProfileName (the ProfileName can change, but the ProfileID won't) into a test class would seem to be helpful as well.

Comment: Wholeheartedly agree, would help those on developer.force.com Forum as well. I would add to the list of stuff to look out for/best practices - (1) differences in validation rules/workflows/sharing rules betw PROD and sandbox; (2) How to get test coverage of catch blocks; (3) how to avoid to reduce test elapsed time by using batches of inputs

Answer (score 4):

Yeah I think that's a smart idea. Happy to donate content from my blog post which tackled this the other week after seeing so many questions about it:

http://www.laceysnr.com/2013/11/debugging-salesforcecom-deployments.html

Comment: someone start it, and link the Q