# I'm in two minds about this question

Tags: discussion

I'm in two minds about this question:
[Sales Cloud Certification sample implementation assigment](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/21278/sales-cloud-certification-sample-implementation-assigment)

On the surface I'd say it's way too open and high level, but then I did consider the idea that we could have one wiki answer for it and actually build something up that helps people. What do you guys reckon?

Comment: I agree, the only option for such a question to stay is wiki-style. Either covert it now, or edit it to by known that it will change to a wiki.

Answer (score 2):

I responded to the question.  I interpreted the question as asking if there was an existing workbook/assignment for the Sales Cloud Consultant exam, similar to how the Force.com Fundamentals book is a fairly comprehensive book for preparing for the Developer certification.  I didn't interpret it as asking us to create an assignment, although it is kind of worded that way.

There does not exist one, as far as I know, so I suggested writing a functional spec for the implementation that is in the Salesforce online training course that walks through a Sales Cloud implementation from a Sales Cloud Consultant's point of view.

There might be a third party workbook or training that has an example implementation that someone else might know about.

Answer (score 2):

Initially, I liked the wiki idea, but then I thought about extending it since we've had similar questions regarding ADM201 and DEV401. Could/should we create training exercises for those certification as well?

Here's why I decided I don't like the wiki idea and think the question should be closed: this site is about specific problems and not about giving general training. Yes, there's enough knowledge here to create a fairly comprehensive implementation problem, but that's [not the type of question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) for this site. If we did that for one question or part of Salesforce people would expect it for others and I worry about a slippery slope.

**Note:** I do like wiki answers, especially the [idea proposed for testing code](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/483/test-code-and-test-classes-we-need-a-wiki). I see that one differently because we the same questions come up frequently and it would be nice to have a canonical answer to refer new users.